# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Intro') when including material-intro in my project

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I wanted to add an intro wizard for my app (when you first use it).
I used this library as the source: https://github.com/HeinrichReimer/material-intro
So basically what I did was copying his library folder to my project root location and after building the project I get the following error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Intro').
```

More detailed error log:

```
C:\Users\abhishek rai\AndroidStudioProjects\DonationApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(30, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Intro').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\abhishek  rai\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The code in *AndroidManifest.xml* is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="minor.da.com.donationapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="minor.da.com.donationapp.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="minor.da.com.donationapp.MaterialIntroActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="minor.da.com.donationapp.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Intro" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="minor.da.com.donationapp.FinishActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="minor.da.com.donationapp.Front_page"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="minor.da.com.donationapp.SecondPage" />
    <activity
        android:name="android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity"
        android:label="RecyclerViewTestActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the source is not what you would normally do if you use an Android library like **material-intro** and I'm clearly discouraging you to do so.
You should definitely include it as a Gradle dependency as described in its readme:

Put that in your **project**'s *build.gradle*:

```
allprojects {
    //...
    repositories {
        //...
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}
```

And then put that in your **module**'s *build.gradle*:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.2.1'
}
```

If you yet run into troubles then, please update the question to include your Gradle files.

Comment: thanks man.Actually i am new to android and this was my first time i am using a Github code for my project and yes i am fully aware that copying a code is not a solution.i was in a hurry to submit my project and thanks to you again for the help.this will be our first big project .@heinrich